# shared \include files.. how to intelligently interpret root directory?

Tags: compiling

I have a directory with a paper in it.  It has various subdirectories with stuff in them.

```
paper1/
    main.tex
    intro/
        intro.tex
    conclusion/
        conclusion.tex
    static/
        image1.png
        image2.png
```

paper1's main.tex looks something like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\include{intro/intro}
\include{conclusion/conclusion}
\end{document}
```

and paper1's intro includes my static images:

```
\includegraphics{static/image1}
```

Works great, cool.

Now, however, I am composing all of these papers together into my dissertation.  I would like to be able to just `\include` my papers in my document.  I made symbolic links to paper1 in my dissertation folder:

```
dissertation/
    thesis.tex
    paper1/
        ...
```

And would like to do something like the following in thesis.tex:

```
\begin{document}
\include{paper1/intro/intro}
\end{document}
```

However, when I try to compile this, the paths to the graphics in paper1/intro/intro.tex fail to resolve, since they assume a root directory of paper1/.  I now have a root directory of dissertation/.  I am willing to re-do the paths in paper1/intro/intro.tex, but I would like to be either to compile paper1 or to compile dissertation as I wish without having to "switch" the paths back and forth.  Possibly there is a clever way to do the directory structuring and such.

Is there a way to compile latex files with shared \includes, intelligently setting the root directory as needed?

Comment: Try `\include{../intro/intro}`

Comment: simplest is simply to use `\include{intro}` and put your `dissertation//` directory into TEXINPUTS then any file recursively under that directory will be found by filename alone

Comment: @JohnKormylo, do you mean in the dissertation/thesis.tex file?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, but I think that this doesn't fix the problem of the static/image1.png files resolving correctly?

Comment: @Scott includegraphics uses the same path so you could use `\includegraphics{image1.png}` no need for paths in the file, but I put some more possibilities in an answer

Comment: TeX uses UNIX style pathnames.  `../` backs up into the parent directory.

Answer (score 2):

the paths are taken relative to the working directory of the tex process, not of the document so you could use `pdflatex thesis` and `pdflatex paper1/paper` but it's usually better to run pdflatex in the directory of the document so this isn't necessarily recommended/

You could simply to use `\include{intro}` and put your `/some/path/dissertation//:` into TEXINPUTS environment variable then any file recursively under that directory will be found by filename alone.

as a third option use

```
\include{\paperone/intro/intro}
```

and in the paper1 file have

```
\providecommand\paperone{.}
```

but in the thesis have

```
\newcommand\paperone{paper1}
```

so if you run the thesis you input `paper1/intro/intro.tex` but if you run the paper1 document you input `./intro/intro.tex`